# Initial View App Delegate Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having some issues getting my app to properly launch the correct View Controller on boot-up.  I have the initial view controller set inside the main.Storyboard with the arrow.  However part of my app features chat.  Inside my AppDelegate.M file under didfinishLaunchingWithOptions I have this coding:

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.groupView = [[GroupView alloc] init];
    self.privateView = [[PrivateView alloc] init];
    self.messagesView = [[MessagesView alloc] init];
    self.profileView = [[ProfileView alloc] init];

    NavigationController *navController1 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.groupView];
    NavigationController *navController2 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.privateView];
    NavigationController *navController3 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.messagesView];
    NavigationController *navController4 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.profileView];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4, nil];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = DEFAULT_TAB;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return YES;
}
```

I guess I'm too much of a noob to know exactly how to fix this...but let me explain a little better what is going on.  My chat was done in XIB and the rest of my app is done on StoryBoards interface.  The ViewController that I want people to see is called CRViewController and is connected to a tabBarController (which I have not named), That view looks like this:
[image: Main Menu]

Because of my appdelegate coding the view that pops up instead is called WelcomeView and also has a tabbarcontroller.  (note: tabBarController for this view is presented after user login) That View Looks like this:
[image: Chat Welcome Screen]

My question is this:  What do I have to change in order to show my CRViewController on boot-up?  Also is there a way to add navigation from my chat XIB navigation bar back to my CRViewController that also will present my CRViewController with the Main Menu TabBar?  If more information is needed please don't hesitate to ask!  Thank you!

Comment: The code you have in the app delegate overrides the initial view controller that you set up in the storyboard. If you don't want that to happen, then move this code to one of your controllers (which ever one is the controller you want to see before the tab bar controller).

Comment: So I would want to move this from my AppDelegate.m to WelcomeView.m, however in the AppDelegate this code is under didfinishlaunchingwithoptions, where would I place this coding inside of my Welcome.m file?

Comment: You were right @rdelmar.  I had to put the coding in my initial view controller.  Specifically in my IBAction that would call the Chat View to be shown.  Thank you!  If you make this an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

For setting your `CRViewController` as the initial view controller. You need to change your `didfinishLaunchingWithOptions` like:

```
CRViewController *crv = [[CRViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = crv;
```

Or in your Storyboard give a Storyboard Id and change the above code like:

```
CRViewController *crv = (CRViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourCRVId"];
self.window.rootViewController = crv;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that yesterday and for whatever reason this presents me with a black screen.

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic: Check whether you added that class to your viewcontroller in the storyboard/xib

Comment: [link] http://s12.postimg.org/l5htv59xp/Screen_Shot_2015_01_25_at_11_13_41_AM.png [link]

Comment: Getting these errors:  [link] http://s14.postimg.org/ph5xj89s1/Screen_Shot_2015_01_25_at_11_40_01_AM.png [link]

Comment: I gave the CRViewController a Storyboard ID of CRViewControllerID.

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic: That's my mistake. Edited the answer. Can you check now ?

Comment: ok, I did that, I have my tabbarcontroller (MainMenuTabBarController) set as the initial view controller in Storyboard.  Upon Start-up it now goes to my CRViewController but without the tab bar present.  If I goto Chat from the CRViewController and Login it returns me to the CRView Controller.

Comment: I ended up changing the coding above to refer to my TabBarController instead of my CRViewController.  This presents my tabbar upon launch with my CRViewController.  However now when I try to log into the chat it wont log me in.

Comment: The initial view is what I want it to be.  But say if I tap on the Chat button on the Main Menu, it will take me to the WelcomeView, however clicking on Facebook Login, Email Register, or Email Login, will no longer work.  Tapping on any of them gives me no response.

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic: How did you write code for navigating to above mentioned pages ?

Comment: MainMenuTabBarControllerViewController *MMTBC = (MainMenuTabBarControllerViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MMTBCTC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = MMTBC;

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic: Check `MMTBC` is nil or not.

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: @DiplomaticMedic: put a break point and check or put NSLog(@"%@",MMTBC);

Comment: 2015-01-25 12:42:10.841 Contractor Rich[15880:576641] <MainMenuTabBarControllerViewController: 0x7fcf1a49bfc0>

Comment: is it because after we have changed the rootViewController to MMTBC that we are not calling the Chat Tab Bar Controller that was created in the coding above it?

Comment: [link] http://s11.postimg.org/8g1mmjm5f/Screen_Shot_2015_01_25_at_12_46_50_PM.png [link]

Answer (score 0):

Set CRViewController as initial rootViewController.

```
CRViewController *crv = [[CRViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = crv;
```

After successfully login just change the rootViewCOntroller of your app.

```
if(loggedIn) {
    //Change the rootViewController
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)